# Convert flattened list to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the list containing strings and numbers. I am trying to convert into dictionary based on the type if it is string otherwise it would become a key.

Input:

```
lst = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]
```

Output:

```
[{'A': [1, 3, 4]}, {'B': [5]}, {'C': [2]}, {'D': 4}]
```

This is my working code so far, I it is definitely not as optimized as it could be:

```
main_array = []
small_array = []
se = {}
key = None
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    print(i)
    if i == len(lst)-2:
        if type(lst[i]) == str and type(lst[i+1]) == str:
            main_array.append(lst[i])
            main_array.append(lst[i+1])
        elif type(lst[i]) == str and type(lst[i+1]) != str:
            main_array.append({lst[i]: lst[i+1]})
        elif type(lst[i]) != str and type(lst[i+1]) == str:
            small_array.append(lst[i])
            se.update({key: small_array})
            main_array.append(se)
            se = {}
            small_array = []
            main_array.append(lst[i+1])
        elif lst[i] != type(str) and lst[i + 1] != type(str):
            small_array.append(lst[i])
            small_array.append(lst[i+1])
            se.update({key: small_array})
            main_array.append(se)
            se = {}
            small_array = []
    else:
        if type(lst[i]) == str and i != len(lst)-1:
            if type(lst[i+1]) == str:
                main_array.append(lst[i])
            elif type(lst[i+1]) != str:
                key = lst[i]
        elif type(lst[i]) != str and i != len(lst)-1:
            if type(lst[i+1]) == str:
                small_array.append(lst[i])
                se.update({key: small_array})
                main_array.append(se)
                se = {}
                small_array = []
            elif type(lst[i+1]) != str:
                small_array.append(lst[i])
print(main_array)
```

Is there any way to optimize this code as I am intending to avoid nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a temporary `list` variable to build up the list until you encounter a `str` value in the list:

```py
L = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]

res = {}
curr: list

for e in L:
    if type(e) == str:
        res[e] = curr = []
    else:
        curr.append(e)

print(res)
```

Print:

```
{'A': [1, 3, 4], 'B': [5], 'C': [2], 'D': [4]}
```

In case you really want a list of single-value `dict` elements:

```py
L = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]

res = []

add = list.append
curr: list

for e in L:
    if type(e) == str:
        curr = []
        add(res, {e: curr})
    else:
        add(curr, e)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'A': [1, 3, 4]}, {'B': [5]}, {'C': [2]}, {'D': [4]}]
```

---

I was actually curious, so I timed it. It seems close to **40%** faster than using an approach with `defaultdict`.

```py
from timeit import timeit
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

L = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]

# 1.385
print('dict:          ', timeit("""
res = []

add = list.append
curr: list

for e in L:
    if type(e) == str:
        curr = []
        add(res, {e: curr})
    else:
        add(curr, e)
""", globals=globals()))

# 1.619
print('no temp list:  ', timeit("""
res = []
key = None
add = list.append

for el in L:
    if type(el) == str:
        key = el
        add(res, {el: []})
        continue
    add(res[-1][key], el)
""", globals=globals()))

# 2.150
print('defaultdict:   ', timeit("""
dct = defaultdict(list)
key = None

for el in L:
    if type(el) == str:
        key = el
    else:
        dct[key].append(el)

result = [{key: dct[key]} for key in dct]
""", globals=globals()))

# 2.578
print('groupby:       ', timeit("""
groups = groupby(L, type)
result = []
try:
    while groups:
        result.append({ list(next(groups)[1])[0] : list(next(groups)[1]) })
except StopIteration:
    pass
""", globals=globals()))
```

Comment: This method is indeed faster, however, you really don't need to be storing a `curr` list on its own. It can live inside the `res` list. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74230438/13376511)

Answer (score 3):

It is much better to create an intermediate dictionary, then convert that dictionary to your desired result. Like this:

```
import collections

lst = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]

dct = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [])
key = None
for el in lst:
    if type(el) == str:
        key = el
        continue
    dct[key].append(el)

result = [{key: dct[key]} for key in dct]
print(result)
```

Comment: @Nick Sorry. When that comment was posted, there was only one answer.

Comment: what is the reason for `result = [{key: dct[key]} for key in dct]`? that just makes it slower as it has to reiterate over the k-v pairs again. I assume this is to convert defaultdict back to dict, but I'm honestly not sure if it's needed. In fact, even `dict(dct)` seems to be faster overall.

Comment: @rv.kvetch You're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: actually that might have been my bad. I didn't read the question too carefully, looks like he wanted a list of single-element `dict` elements. I'm not sure what the use case for that is, however I realized that your answer gave the correct output to how the OP had it above.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Haha yes. I've rolled back my edit

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to simply add a new dictionary every time a string comes up, then append to that list until the next string. Like this:

```
lst = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]

res = []
key = None
for el in lst:
    if type(el) == str:
        key = el
        res.append({el: []})
        continue
    res[-1][key].append(el)

print(res)
```

I believe that this would be much faster than [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74230235/13376511). All you need is one result array and one variable to keep track of the key.

---

When I tested it, this method is slightly slower than [rv.kvetch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74230248/13376511), however there is no need to store a temporary list. This method is cleaner (no need to add the last list) and uses less memory in theory.

Comment: right, and I believe I might understand the slight difference in times. I think it is the access times in this case, i.e. `res[-1][key]` as it involves accessing the last item in a `list` and then a key in a `dict`. I am not entirely convinced that it uses less memory, as in my case I only use a temp variable, which I assume is pretty cheap overall. However, still  +1 for a clean alternative solution.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it without the last line to account for the last element. I think I just wasn't thinking about too clearly earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your list by the type of value, then iterate the result to get the key and value pairs for each dict to be pushed to the result list:

```py
import itertools

lst = ['A', 1, 3, 4, 'B', 5, 'C', 2, 'D', 4]
groups = itertools.groupby(lst, type)
result = []
try:
    while groups:
        result.append({ list(next(groups)[1])[0] : list(next(groups)[1]) })
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Output:

```
[
 {'A': [1, 3, 4]},
 {'B': [5]},
 {'C': [2]},
 {'D': [4]}
]
```

Comment: Hmm, seems like `lambda x: type(x)` might be a bit redundant. I also timed it and just `type` without a lambda appears to be much faster overall.

Comment: @rv.kvetch d'oh! I originally had an actual function there and just blindly replaced it with type. I've edited, thanks. It's still not as fast as either yours or the other answer though. Out of curiosity I tested all of them with a longer list (`lst * 200000`) and the `defaultdict` approach was easily the fastest, 16.8 vs 33.7 (yours) and 47.1 (mine)

Comment: Agreed, `defaultdict` is indeed faster when lst is much larger in size like mentioned. I'm curious about why that is, I guess it could be because it appears to be implemented in C and uses optimizations that I don't know much about.

Comment: @rv.kvetch yeah, it is weird, because the operation of the two bits of code is essentially identical - at least on the surface. It would be interesting to compare with long lists which have few letters and many integers; I suspect the advantage must be coming from the initialisation of the element, in which case the performance of the two would be much closer.